# How to detect if my iFrame is used by another website?

Tags: javascript, iframe, domexception

I make web games. I upload them to portals like Newgrounds. They are being embedded as iFrames on those sites. However, I noticed that other sites "steal" the games by embedding the iFrames on their own websites. Is there any code I can run in my iFrame to detect which site I am embedded on?

I keep searching and a lot of threads say something like

```
if (window.top.location.hostname != "myhost.com") {
    console.log("Not on myhost");
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work these days due to DOMExceptions. Anything else I can do? Or did I miss something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simply tell if the page is embedded in an iframe by checking `window.top` itself:

```
if (window != window.top) {
    console.log("In an iframe");
}
```

I think the code you posted should only get an exception if the parent page is in a different domain. So you could just check for the error:

```
try {
    var = window.top.location.hostname;
} catch (e) {
    console.log("In an iframe from another domain");
}
```

Comment: My game is posted as an iFrame in both cases. 

Also, Newgrounds seems to host the game on a server with a different domain than their frontend.

So sadly, neither of those tests will distinguish between the original and fraudulent website.